Why do I need to assign to `output.next` in this solution for Merge Sorted Linked Lists?
The correct solution below for the Merge Two Sorted Linked Lists Leetcode problem fails when you remove the .next in lines 12, 15, 24:
output.next = list1 becomes output = list1
output.next = list2 becomes output = list2
return head.next becomes return head
Correct solution
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        head = output = ListNode()

        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                output.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                output.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            output = output.next

        if list1 and output:
            output.next = list1
        elif list2 and output:
            output.next = list2

        return head.next

I expected it to work exactly the same. When I print output within the loop, it prints the remaining tail of the current list that's lesser than.

Assignment to a variable doesn't mutate your tree, it only affects that content of that variable. You must assign to an attribute (.next) to effectively update that attribute.

See also When does a pointer to a linked list change the actual list?
